# Get UIViewController associated with a UITabBarItem

Tags: iphone, ipad, uikit, uiviewcontroller

I have a UITabBarController with a bunch of tabs.
When a new tab is selected, I want to be able to access the UIViewController associated with that tab.

The `-(void)tabBar:(UITabBar*)tabBar didSelectItem:(UITabBarItem*)item` method on UITabBarDelegate gives me access only to the UITabBarItem.

Any suggestions on how go from this to the UIViewController that's displaying the contents of the selected tab?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why not use [`.selectedViewController` of UITabBarController](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instp/UITabBarController/selectedViewController)?

Also, the UITabBar's `.delegate` is controlled by the tab bar controller. If you change it, the controller will not function properly. Use [UITabBarController's `.delegate`](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITabBarController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006931-CH3-SW7) instead.